# How do Fender wide-range pickups change the sound?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, sound, tone, pick-ups

Billie Joe Armstrong's blue strat has a tilted pickup in the back, its tilted a bit clockwise from the front of the guitar,  so the pickup gets more lower end and and a extended higher end, it gives it a more wider sound right? So.. my question is whether fender wide range pickups sound almost the same?

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](https://equipboard.com/pros/billie-joe-armstrong/fernandes-stratocaster-blue) and included video in which Billie Joe's tech discusses his setups, including "Blue"

Comment: Hi Aloysius, welcome to Music.SE! I've edited your question title so it's more clear what you're asking; feel free to change this if you think it could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wide Range, like the pickups in the 70s Fender Deluxe?

Going by [the Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fender_Wide_Range), you don't lose as much high end with them, but they require more winds and are bigger than PAF-based ones. For years, you could get ones from Fender that *look* like the 70s pickups, but they didn't have the CuNIFe magnets and didn't sound the same. I read online that only a few makers got that sound right, but while I'm leaning on it being Lollar who got it right, I cannot remember fully, but I know that many other boutique makers have developed their own and Fender USA is making more accurate versions.

I'm sure there's *some* tone effect from the angle, but EVH did it so that a Gibson-built PAF would handle the spring spacing of his Strat-copy body. If I was to make a Billie Joe copy, going with a Seymour Duncan JB in the bridge seems the obvious choice, and in not sure that angling it would be necessary if you can find a trembucker style, which adjusts to the Fender string spacing. I'm pretty sure that the Wide Range wouldn't fit in a swimming pool route, and and getting the right pickguard that will take one seems difficult.

But I'm some guy on the internet. If you want to give it a shot, do it.